# Hangouts is using obscene amounts of background data

Tags: root-access, lineageos, oneplus-3, 7.1-nougat

248 Mb this last week of background data compared to 41 Mb foreground. Last month was 400/100. How do I go about seeing what's the cause? I don't send/receive many pictures, when I do it's usually a Hangouts message, not MMS, but usually on wifi too. My brother is 441 foreground, 85 background fore comparison, so about opposite. But as frequently as we're on wifi, I wouldn't think it should use that much cellular data.

Anyone have any tips or a way to start investigating what's going on?

Edit: doesn't fix the root cause, but disabling background cellular data usage doesn't stop you from getting notifications through the magic of GCM push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It used 1.5GB in less than a day for me a couple of weeks ago, so I've turned off background data for the app. Makes it pretty crippled, but only option. I can't find any answer to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Just noticed your comment regarding push, great to know. Initially I uninstalled Hangouts, but yesterday thought I'd try again and the last hour 250MB disappeared, do I turned off background data instead of deleting the app again. I also turned off the feedback option, which obviously didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I just got off chat with Project Fi support.  Here's the workaround they gave me to this bug.

> Project Fi Support:  Please follow the below steps.

1. Open your device's Settings app .
2. Tap Network & Internet and then Data usage.
3. Tap Mobile data usage.
4. To find the app, scroll down.
   **Please select Hangouts over there.
5. To see more details and options, tap the app's name.
6. Change background mobile data usage.
   To restrict background data usage for this app, turn off Background data.

> User:  Done. What functionality have I lost by turning off Background
>   data?

Project Fi Support:  You have not lost any thing. It will just make sure that the data is not used when you are not using Hangouts.
For reference, you can go through this link: https://support.google.com/fi/answer/2819524?hl=en

> User:  So new text messages will still notify me right away when they
>   come in?
>
> Project Fi Support:  Yes, you'll be getting the messages if the data
>   is on.